# Deeplinking in Samsung Messaging App with Built In Browser

Tags: android, branch.io

I'm using branch.io for deeplinking in my app and so far everything has been perfect except for our Galaxy S7 edge running the native Samsung Messages app. The new Samsung Messages app now opens links in a webview in the messaging app instead of opening it externally. So since it's opening the link in the messaging app's internal webview instead of chrome or internet app the deeplink is not working.

Has anyone else seen this issue and have come up with a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

a Branch colleague of mine just looked into this. He found that links do not redirect properly when utilizing URI based deep linking from the native Samsung SMS app on the S7, however App Links do work and you can enable them in your Branch Dashboard here: https://dashboard.branch.io/settings/link -- documentation: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/guide/android/

Let me know how it goes. If you continue to struggle we can check it out 1:1 over e-mail.

Comment: Thank you! Will get back to you some time this week.

Comment: Not sure how to contact you directly. I have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: hey @kkl260 -- you can reach me here: integrations@branch.io -- please reference this issue with a link when writing in, and include your Branch app id found at the bottom of the page here: https://dashboard.branch.io/settings -- i'll check out your settings and see what's going on!

Comment: @kkl260 you mention that you did get it working, can you share with us how you did?

Comment: @kkl260 did you find a solution in the end at all?

Comment: Hey @dirkvranckaert  we patched the Branch link service today to handle a Samsung browser routing issue that could be affecting this one. I'm able to deep link correctly from Messages on my s8 with App Links configured properly. Let me know if you have any luck!

Answer (score 0):

add to your intent filter auto verify like below:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
```

source:https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html