# Opening app via sms link doesn't work for some messaging apps

Tags: android, applinks

Samsung default SMS app opens a link in their own WebView instead of launching my app. I've checked with other messaging apps and other phones and it works fine. But testing this with a YouTube link actually launches YouTube app and not the WebView in this messaging app.

http://www.youtube.com/someYouTubeChannel

My app url is in this format:
http://www.myapp.com/app/android

The Manifest for intercepting this looks like:

```
<android:name="com.myapp.MyAppActivity">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="www.myapp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/app/android"
                android:scheme="http"/>

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Is the YouTube app doing something different to intercept all urls? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Its a 3rd party app.  You have no control over what it does.  It isn't even forced to make a URL clickable, much less to have it go to your app.  All you can really do is follow the rules and hope.  But you shouldn't assume that a 3rd party app will handle any specific data in any specific way, unless its part of their public API.

Comment: @GabeSechan so you think they're just making an specific exception for YouTube to open their app?

Comment: In addition, this also happens to the default messaging application of my Xiaomi Pocophone F1 phone. When the link is clicked, what comes out is the browser, not the link that we have set to our application

Answer (score 0):

This could be a new issue specifically with the Samsung messaging app. You can see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702503/deeplinking-in-samsung-messaging-app-with-built-in-browser)

It's possible YouTube is using [verified AppLinks](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#request-verify), or that Samsung has some special handling for the YouTube app.

Comment: i can try to associate my app with my website and see if it will work https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html