# Samsung Messages app won't deep link into my app

Tags: android, sms, samsung-galaxy

I have an app that has the ability to be launched whenever I receive an SMS with a certain format, it works correctly when using the Android stock Messages app but, when testing on a Samsung device using their Messages app and clicking a link, it won't launch my app but instead try and open the link inside the Messages app, current implementation on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.example.SMSInterceptor"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="example.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Anyone know any solution to this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? There's a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702503/deeplinking-in-samsung-messaging-app-with-built-in-browser

Answer (score -1):

add to your intent filter auto verify like below:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
```