# Deeplink in Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, samsung-mobile

I'm having problem with deeplink on some Samsung devices.

This is my manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ActivityLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

            <data
                android:host="deeplink.something.somethingelse"
                android:scheme="http"></data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And my deeplink:

```
   link: http://deepLink.something.somethingelse/bookDoctor
```

On Samsung S7 (or A5) on my default sms application, the links open on internal webview (of the sms application) so my application doesn't catch the intent.
I read a few threads about the same problem for other people:
[Deeplinking in Samsung Messaging App with Built In Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702503/deeplinking-in-samsung-messaging-app-with-built-in-browser)

[Samsung Messages app won't deep link into my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573058/samsung-messages-app-wont-deep-link-into-my-app)

But there is not answer.

Anybody knows what can I do as a developer to avoid getting into Samsung's sms webview?
Samsung are the leading manufacturers for mobile devices, so many users faced this issues. Any solution?

Comment: You can first try to use https and enable Android App Links and see if the messaging app still handles the url in its own browser window. https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html